# map constructor while implement counter in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, counter

I'm trying STL in c++ now and found a question that I didn's understand.
I imagine a problem that needs to show each element and how many times that it occured in a vector. Since I knew how to use vector to finish this problem, I tried to use "set" or "map" to solve the problem.

```
vector<char> v{ 'a', 'b', 'f', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'f', 's', 'v', 'x'};
map<char, int> m; // <key, counter>
for (char n : v)
    m.insert(pair<char, int>(n, m[n]+1));
```

I thought that it will make counter plus each time when key was found, however, counter didn't work and each counter is 0.
After some change:

```
vector<char> v{ 'a', 'b', 'f', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'f', 's', 'v', 'x'};
map<char, int> m; // <key, counter>
for (char n : v)
    m.insert(pair<char, int>(n, m[n]++));
```

Then it work. I don't know why.

Comment: why not use `m[n] += 1` directly? if key is not found, the "new" key is created by default

Comment: @codekaizer: you're right, that would be easier; but Chumicat wanted to know why both versions behave differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a close look at [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) function: It only inserts an element, if it is not yet found!

The [index operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), in contrast, updates an element, if found, and creates a new one with default value otherwise.

So:

```
m.insert(pair<char, int>(n, m[n]+1));
```

The first time you call this, `m[n]` creates already an element with default value 0. Then, you call `insert` on the map, but as the key is already found, no pair is inserted. So you get 0 all the time...

```
m.insert(pair<char, int>(n, m[n]++));
```

Actually, from sight of `insert`, there is no difference: The entry in the map is created the first time you visit the map at position `n`, and you increment the entry directly. `insert` itself *never* actually inserts a pair...

So if you cut off the "do nothing" piece of code, all that remains is:

```
for (char n : v)
    m[n]++;
```

For better understanding, a variant using `insert` equivalent to my code sample above:

```
for (char n : v)
    (m.insert(std::pair<char, int>(n, 0)).first->second)++;
```

Interesting, isn't it? Breaking it into pieces:

```
for (char n : v)
{
    std::pair<std::map<char, int>::iterator, bool> result = m.insert(std::pair<char, int>(n, 0));
    std::pair<char const, int>& entry = *result.first;
    entry.second++;
}
```

The core part of is this line:

```
std::pair<std::map<char, int>::iterator, bool> result = m.insert(std::pair<char, int>(n, 0));
```

The bool of the pair is set to true, if the element actually was inserted and to false otherwise. As not interested in this piece of information in the specific case, not used any further.

The iterator points to the element in the map - either the newly created one (bool part is true), or the one already found (bool part is false).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your attempts to update map entries by calling `insert` are all ignored, because `insert` doesn't do anything if an entry already exists. To quote from the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

It gets a little clearer if you rewrite your code a little:

```
for (char n : v)
{
    int& count = m[n];
    int new_count = count + 1;
    pair<char, int> p(n, new_count);
    m.insert(p); // ignored because the key already exists
}
```

The second version, though, directly modifies the count that's inside the map, due to the `operator[]` returning a *reference* to the stored value, and the `operator++` directly manipulating the `int`. Your second version rewitten would look something like this:

```
for (char n : v)
{
    int& count = m[n];
    count++; // operates on the value that is stored in the map
    pair<char, int> p(n, count);
    m.insert(p); // ignored because the key already exists
}
```

Even though your attempt to insert a new pair into the map is ignored again, since you directly modify the value that's stored in the map, the second version does what you wanted your code to do in the first place.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I know what had happened.